# How do I restore phabricator if I deleted the files but the database is still intact?

Tags: phabricator

So, I did a stupid rm -rf on the folder where the complete phabricator folder was present.

The whole phabricator database is still intact though.

I cloned the required repos on the same old location:

```
somewhere/ $ git clone https://github.com/phacility/libphutil.git
somewhere/ $ git clone https://github.com/phacility/arcanist.git
somewhere/ $ git clone https://github.com/phacility/phabricator.git
```

Apache was already configured during previous install.

I then ran:

```
./bin/storage upgrade
```

After which I went to the address which pointed to phabricator folder. Now I get the following error:

> 1146: Table 'phabricator_user.user_cache' doesn't exist

How do I resolve it? Or in general, what's the best way to reinstall phabricator using the old database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you still have the database, make a mysqldump from the data (export the db data -  you should have this by default - a cron job, running a backup script on another backup machine/usb/hard/cloud)

Do a fresh reinstall on phabricator(EVEN on whole LAMP).

Import the previous backup.sql you did.

After setting the user/passwd/host/port/ in the "path_to_phab/conf/local/local.json" via the command line or simply editing the file, try to run the

```
./bin/storage upgrade
```

This should work fine if you have the storage engine set to mysql db (not-recommended). If you have a different storage engine (like hdd) try to restore data reproducing the path to where you have data in phab`s fresh installation conf files along with mysql import.